# JavaFX How do I return the cursor to the first line in TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TextArea where I type something into it and it would be shown on the second TextArea. But whenever I press enter inside the TextArea to trigger the EventHandler, the cursor goes to the second line. If I press enter again,
the cursor stays at the second line. How do I make sure that the cursor stays at the first line if I press enter?

```
public class NewClass2 {
public NewClass2(Stage stage) {
    initGUI(stage);
}
private void initGUI(Stage stage) {
    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    TextArea text = new TextArea();
    textArea.setWrapText(true);
    text.setWrapText(true);
    text.setPrefColumnCount(1);
    text.setPrefRowCount(1);
    text.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        boolean once = false;
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)  {
                String message = text.getText();
                text.setText("");
                textArea.appendText(": " + message + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                //text.setText("");
                //text.clear();
            }
        }
    });

    flowPane.getChildren().add(textArea);
    flowPane.getChildren().add(text);

    Scene scene = new Scene(flowPane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652062/javafx-2-textarea-how-to-stop-it-from-consuming-enter-and-tab