# JavaFX disable tab navigation

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a console application and I would like to autocomplete commands when pressing tab. The problem is that when you press tab in javaFX it switches focus to another element in the application. Any way to disable this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657680/259889

Comment: @Reborn Isn't this question asking the direct opposite of the question you linked?

Comment: @James_D Ops. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event filter and consume the event:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DisableFocusNavigation extends Application {

    private TextField createTextField() {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                System.out.println("Tab pressed");
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        return textField ;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField tf1 = createTextField();
        TextField tf2 = createTextField();

        VBox root = new VBox(5, tf1, tf2);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't particularly good practice, as it makes it impossible to use the application without a mouse (or similar input device). You should at least check for modifier keys in the event filter, and allow for some focus traversal options.